# Throws exception when trying to open any dialog If the "MaterialConfiguration" provided in "Material.Init()" using XF-Material-Library

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, material-design

I'm using XF-Material-Library in my Xamarin.forms, so When I tried to change the default theme of the library by providing an object of type `MaterialConfiguration` in the `XF.Material.Forms.Material.Init()` method, it keeps throwing exception when trying to open any dialog, even the dialog of the MaterialTextField (with `InputType="Choice"` and choices list) which is auto-opens by the library.

here is exception message:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 22:32. StaticResource not found for key Material.Dialog.Width
```

here is the full exception:

```
{Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 22:32. StaticResource not found for key Material.Dialog.Width  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.StaticResourceExtension.ProvideValue (System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider) [0x0008f] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\MarkupExtensions\StaticResourceExtension.cs:27   at XF.Material.Forms.UI.Dialogs.MaterialSimpleDialog.InitializeComponent () [0x00055] in C:\Users\mhvdi\Documents\OpenSource\XF-Material-Library\XF.Material\obj\Release\monoandroid10.0\UI\Dialogs\MaterialSimpleDialog.xaml.g.cs:38   at XF.Material.Forms.UI.Dialogs.MaterialSimpleDialog..ctor (XF.Material.Forms.UI.Dialogs.Configurations.MaterialSimpleDialogConfiguration configuration) [0x00006] in C:\Users\mhvdi\Documents\OpenSource\XF-Material-Library\XF.Material\UI\Dialogs\MaterialSimpleDialog.xaml.cs:21   at XF.Material.Forms.UI.Dialogs.MaterialSimpleDialog.ShowAsync (System.String title, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] actions, XF.Material.Forms.UI.Dialogs.Configurations.MaterialSimpleDialogConfiguration configuration) [0x00014] in C:\Users\mhvdi\Documents\OpenSource\XF-Material-Library\XF.Material\UI\Dialogs\MaterialSimpleDialog.xaml.cs:31  at UiTest.ViewModels.AboutViewModel.<.ctor>b__17_2 () [0x0006c] in C:\Projects\UiTest\UiTest\UiTest\ViewModels\AboutViewModel.cs:83 }
```

And here is my code in App.xaml.cs :

```
XF.Material.Forms.Material.Init(this, new MaterialConfiguration
            {
                ColorConfiguration = new MaterialColorConfiguration
                {
                    Background = Color.FromHex("#EAEAEA"),
                    Error = Color.FromHex("#B00020"),
                    OnBackground = Color.FromHex("#000000"),
                    OnError = Color.FromHex("#FFFFFF"),
                    OnPrimary = Color.FromHex("#FFFFFF"),
                    OnSecondary = Color.FromHex("#FFFFFF"),
                    OnSurface = Color.FromHex("#000000"),
                    Primary = Color.FromHex("#2196f3"),
                    PrimaryVariant = Color.FromHex("#03A9F4"),
                    Secondary = Color.FromHex("#29b6f6"),
                    SecondaryVariant = Color.FromHex("#0086c3"),
                    Surface = Color.FromHex("#FFFFFF")
                }
            });
```

**Note: for now, I'm only working with Android.**

I tried also to use App.xaml to add my configurations as the documentation described, but it didn't work for me, so I have tried to add my configurations in cs file.

Comment: Make sure you have followed all the steps mentioned here : https://github.com/Baseflow/XF-Material-Library

Comment: @FreakyAli that's exactly what I have done, but it keeps throw this exception when ever I try to open a dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> copied from [XF-Material_library issues](https://github.com/Baseflow/XF-Material-Library/issues/390) on GitHub that solved by [dm-CaT](https://github.com/dm-CaT)

I've faced the same issue. There is no possibility to avoid it when you're configuring Material from code. You have to configure it via resource dictionary. The steps are:

1. Add resources in app.xaml

```
 <Application.Resources>


    <mat:MaterialColorConfiguration x:Key="Material.Color"
        Background="#e1e1e1"
        Error="#B00020"
        OnBackground="#2f3232"
        OnError="#ffffff"
        OnPrimary="#ffffff"
        OnSecondary="#2f3232"
        OnSurface="#2f3232"
        Primary="#585b5b"
        PrimaryVariant="#2f3232"
        Secondary="#ef7d39"
        SecondaryVariant="#ffae67"
        Surface="#f5f5f5" />

    <mat:MaterialConfiguration x:Key="Material.Configuration" ColorConfiguration="{StaticResource Material.Color}"/>

</Application.Resources>
```

2. Initialize Material in app.xaml.cs before InitializeComponent() call.
3. Apply theme from resources to Material after InitializeComponent() call.

```
 Material.Init(this);
 InitializeComponent();
 Material.Use("Material.Configuration");
```